# MacOS swift error - VZVirtualMachine The maximum supported number of active virtual machines has been reached

Tags: swift, macos, virtual-machine, apple-silicon

I'm using [`KhaosT/MacVM`](https://github.com/KhaosT/MacVM) which uses [`VZVirtualMachine`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/virtualization/vzvirtualmachine)  to create the virtual machine on Apple Silicon host but for some reason, I'm starting to get the following error (I haven't got that before):

```
Error: Error Domain=VZErrorDomain Code=6
  "The maximum supported number of active virtual machines has been reached."
  UserInfo={
    NSLocalizedFailure=A software update is required to complete this installation.,
    NSLocalizedFailureReason=The maximum supported number of active virtual machines has been reached.
  }
```

The following code starts the VM (from [here](https://github.com/KhaosT/MacVM/blob/b7192e7d529ae61ebdd33c884e477fe9e01ac9b7/MacVM/VMInstance.swift#L175-L186)):

```swift
let vm = VZVirtualMachine(configuration: configuration, queue: .main)
vm.delegate = self
vm.start { [weak self] result in
    switch result {
    case .success:
        self?.document?.isRunning = true
        NSLog("Success")
    case .failure(let error): // <-- This catch the thrown error 
        NSLog("Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Is there some limit? if so how can I change it?

Maybe a relevant issue is that the IP keep increasing every VM reboot [`KhaosT/MacVM#28`](https://github.com/KhaosT/MacVM/issues/28) which maybe some cleaning missing